# nginx reverse proxy to IIS

Tags: iis, nginx, proxy

Have a Nginx box on the DMZ that is to proxy trough to a IIS box on the LAN.

I can get to the home page OK via the Nginx box however after navigating further it seems to re-direct rather than proxy.

Is there additional config needed either on the IIS or Nginx side?

```
server {
        listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name internal.lan.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://internal.lan.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_redirect off;

    }
}
```